# Upload a folder to an S3 bucket using java aws sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I'm trying to upload an entire folder to AWS S3 bucket. I'm successful at uploading individual files, but couldn't find a way to upload the entire folder. 
AWS CLI has an option called `sync`, does and equivalent methods available in Java SDK?

Sample code for uploading individual objects is as below (only part)

```java
final PutObjectRequest dashboardUploadRequest = PutObjectRequest.builder()
                        .bucket(aws.getApplihealthReportBucket())
                        .key(projectName + "/"+ executionConfig.getTestType() +"/" + aws.getS3Folder() + "/index.html").build();

S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder().credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider).build()
s3.putObject(dashboardUploadRequest, Paths.get(resultsDirectory + "/extent.html"));
```

Comment: The `aws s3 sync` command is a Python program that loops through each file and copies each file individually. There is no AWS API for copying multiple files in one call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no way to upload folder directly to s3. Only forearch and upload file by file.

Or using CLI
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Answer (score 1):

The [TransferManager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html) API in Java SDK provides methods to [upload a directory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html#uploadDirectory-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-boolean-) to S3.

Comment: Keep in mind, this is only available for version 1, not 2.